# "killed" message from cron.daily, but not when run from command line

Tags: cron

On Fedora 17, I put a file into `/etc/cron.daily` with the following contents:

```
cd /
su dstahlke /home/dstahlke/bin/anacron-daily.sh
exit 0
```

For some reason, I get a mail every day that just says

```
/etc/cron.daily/dstahlke-daily:

 ...killed.
```

I tried with and without the `exit 0` line above (I noticed that some system scripts have that and others don't, I'm not sure of the purpose).  Running `/etc/cron.daily/dstahlke-daily` from the command line as root produces no `...killed` message.  Other than the message, everything seems to work fine.  Putting `set -x` in the above script, as well as in the `/home/dstahlke/bin/anacron-daily.sh` script shows that the `...killed` message happens just after the latter script terminates (or perhaps just after the su command finishes).

What causes the `...killed` message?

Or, is there a more acceptable way to have anacron run a user script daily?  I figured that putting this in `/etc/cron.daily` would help the system coordinate all of the daily tasks rather than potentially running my task concurrently with the system tasks.

Comment: This question has long since disappeared into the tumbleweeds, but I would like to give a hint.  I get the "...killed" message regardless of what su runs.  So, even "su dstahlke ls" gives the message.  I tried using sudo instead of su, but it won't run without a terminal.

Comment: I also get this message, and I would very much like to know what the reason is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did some further investigation, and found that `...killed` is indeed printed by the `su` program, although the print does not come from the upstream coreutils project, it is introduced by coreutils-8.5-pam.patch in the source rpm. There is some history about the origins for adding this on bugzilla ([622700](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=622700), [597928](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=597928) and [240117](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=240117)).

The relevant part of the code is

```
static sig_atomic_t volatile caught_signal = false;
...
/* Signal handler for parent process.  */
static void
su_catch_sig (int sig)
{
  caught_signal = true;
}
```

...

```
static void
create_watching_parent (void)
{
  ...
  sigfillset (&ourset);
  if (sigprocmask (SIG_BLOCK, &ourset, NULL))
    {
      error (0, errno, _("cannot block signals"));
      caught_signal = true;
    }
  if (!caught_signal)
    {
       ...
       action.sa_handler = su_catch_sig;
       ...
         || sigaction (SIGTERM, &action, NULL)
 ...
  if (caught_signal)
    {
      fprintf (stderr, _("\nSession terminated, killing shell..."));
      kill (child, SIGTERM);
    }

  cleanup_pam (PAM_SUCCESS);

  if (caught_signal)
    {
      sleep (2);
      kill (child, SIGKILL);
      fprintf (stderr, _(" ...killed.\n"));
    }
  exit (status);
}
```

So in some way (either directly/indirectly related to cleanup_pam or unrelated) the parent process receives SIGTERM between the second last and the last if tests, and thus only prints the `...killed` message that obviously should have been a continuation of the fprintf above.

All in all that double use of `caught_signal` as both a asynchronous signal handler means and as a local flow control variable inside the function feels like a really dirty hack and I did not like the code. I tested by splitting that up and introduced a kill_child boolean variable to use in the body of the function and then having

```
  if (caught_signal)
    {
kill_child:
      kill_child = true;
      status = 1;
    }

  if (kill_child) {
    {
      fprintf (stderr, _("\nSession terminated, killing shell..."));
      kill (child, SIGTERM);
    }

  cleanup_pam (PAM_SUCCESS);

  if (kill_child)
    {
      sleep (2);
      kill (child, SIGKILL);
      fprintf (stderr, _(" ...killed.\n"));
    }
  exit (status);
}
```

at the end of the function. With that modification I do not get any `....killed` spam from anacron any longer.

---

So a long explanation, and possibly more information than you need. However. I also found out some more, which is good news for you since you do not have to make local modifications to the coreutils package. For cases like running su from cron you are supposed to run the program [runuser](http://danwalsh.livejournal.com/55588.html) [instead](http://www.cyberciti.biz/open-source/command-line-hacks/linux-run-command-as-different-user/). It is sort of "bad" news for me since it makes my findings above less important, but well well :).

Comment: Excellent, thank you very much!  Using runuser works perfectly and saves me from a cron email every morning.